# Blank PNG image using Chart JS . toBase64Image() function

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, chart.js

I am attempting to save a copy of my chart created using Chart.JS graphing libraries.  When I am using the .toBase64Image() function to display or save the .png image I am getting a blank image.  I have tried displaying in an img tag and saving the image with PHP.  save64Img is my function to display/save the image.  Has anyone had any luck using this feature?

```
lineOptions = {
        scaleShowGridLines : true,
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
        bezierCurve : false,
        pointDot : true,
        pointDotRadius : 4,
        pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
        pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
        datasetStroke : true,
        datasetStrokeWidth : 1,
        datasetFill : true,
        responsive: true,      
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleSteps : 5,
        scaleStepWidth : 20,
        scaleStartValue : 0

    }

    lineChart = {
            labels : label,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "stat1",
                    fillColor : "rgba(128,0,0,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(128,0,0,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(128,0,0,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(128,0,0,1)",
                    data : stat1
                },
                {
                    label: "stat2",
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data : stat2
                }
            ]

    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChart, lineOptions);

save64Img(myChart.toBase64Image());

----------

<?php 
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $img));

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's been awhile since you have asked the question, but in the Chart.js v2 you have to use `onComplete` method within the animation option.

```
animation: {
    duration: 1500,
    onComplete: function (animation) { 
        this.toBase64Image();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent hours while found this answer that worked for me.

Comment: Can you please share the full code.

Answer (score -1):

you have to call `save64Img(myChart.toBase64Image())` over an additional callback.
You can add this callback to the options

```
lineOptions = {
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
       save64Img(myChart.toBase64Image());
    }
}
```